# Handling sync.Once in golang testcases

Tags: unit-testing, go, environment-variables, integration-testing, go-gin

I'm getting started with go-gin project. Some properties are initialized in a `sync.Once.Do()` method like below.

```golang
var doItOnce sync.Once
var structObject SomeStruct

func getProperty() SomeStruct {
    doItOnce.Do(func() {
        structObject = SomeStruct{
            Data: os.Getenv("ENV_VARIABLE"),
        }
    })
    return structObject
}

// some other code which is using structObject
```

I'm trying to test the functionality of `structObject` in multiple test cases (all of these test cases are in the same test package). But the problem I'm facing is the initialization of `structObject` which is dependent on an environment variable. I'm trying to use different values for this environment variable `ENV_VARIABLE` in different test cases, but as the `structObject` is part of `sync.Once.Do()` block, it is only accepting the initial value of the environment variable, but not the rest of them.

I'm trying to execute the test cases using the following command.

```bash
go test -coverageprofile=coverage.out -coverpkg=./... ./...
```

Is there any alternative approach I can follow so that `sync.Once.Do` method will be executed once in every test case instead of just once per package level tests? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you run `doItOnce.Do(f)`, extract the logic to a function `f`, and then test `f`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, I'm not trying to test `f`. I'm trying to test whatever `f` is initializing `structObject SomeStruct`.

Comment: Run `f` with different environment variables, and check `SomeStruct`, is what I am saying.

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having a `sync.Once`? What I'm trying to implement is that `sync.Once.Do` block executes `f` once per test case.

Comment: If you want to test the `Once` functionality, you can keep reinitializing it, like `doItOnce=sync.Once{}; test1(); doItOnce=sync.Once{} test2();`

Comment: You don't need to test if `sync.Once` works, we know it works, and it has extensive tests already.

Comment: @JimB, I know that `sync.Once` works and need not be tested. But my problem is that it is getting executed only 1 time for all the test cases in a package instead of 1 time per test case.

Comment: Then you need to refactor so that `sync.Once` isn't called through the path used by tests, or it can be replaced for each test.

Comment: @JimB, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. How do i replace `sync.Once` for each test?